# No RDS environ when using SSH on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I installed Django on AWS EC2 and everything is working fine.

When trying to run commands to administrate Django, I receive an error because I'm missing some environment variables.

**Environnement details:**

- Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-2::platform/Python 3.8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.7
- Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0

For instance, running this from ssh session will fail and say the key doesn't exist:

```
source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate
python3


import os
   print(os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'])
```

How can I get the env variables to be set and usable in SSH?

Note: When Django is run from the server everything works as expected and Django can access the DB, the goal is to be able to manually run commands.

Thank you

Comment: Fail with what error? Show your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and clearly explain what's not working about your attempt.

Comment: Done, hope this help

Comment: Did you even set those ENV variables? If so, how?

Comment: @Marcin Those variables are coming automatically as soon as you attach an RDS database to your environment.
As a matter of fact, Django works perfectly and connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually load those env variables in EB, if you `ssh` to your instance:

```
export $(sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
```

Comment: @PierreAnken Then you have to update your question with more details. Such as what EB environment version are you using? How exactly are you running your scripts? Step by step.

Comment: I updated it again.

Comment: @PierreAnken My answer works as expected. It loads env RDS variables as it should. You have to double check what you are doing. The command must be run as root.

Comment: Thank I finally got it, correct command from SSH his:
export $(sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
to get it as root